# Google sheets query date range between today and the end of next month

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that queries data on another spreadsheet.  I need to return Col1-3 if the date in Col1 >= toDate(now()) and Col1 <= "the last day of next month".

```
=ArrayFormula(query(ImportRange("1YHvYS1-rc1n56CeVeBynZRP6YCtTTyHkVhdu-Wa8E4s=en#","Alt Single Signup!A1:Z200"),"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where (Col1 >= toDate(now()) and Col1<= "the last day of next month")"))
```

I am not sure how to get "the last day of next month". Is there a simple way to figure this out?

*EDIT*
Using the answer below I ended up dropping it in an if stmt to check todays date to pull either till the end of this month or next month.

```
=if(Day(today())<27,query(ImportRange("1YHvYS1-rc1n56CeVeBynZRP6YCtTTyHkVhdu-Wa8E4s=en#","Alt Single Signup!A1:Z200"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3 Where toDate(Col1) > date '"& TEXT( Today() , "yyyy-MM-dd" ) & "'And toDate(Col1 ) <= date '"& TEXT( EOMONTH( Today() , 0) , "yyyy-MM-dd" ) & "' "),query(ImportRange("1YHvYS1-rc1n56CeVeBynZRP6YCtTTyHkVhdu-Wa8E4s=en#","Alt Single Signup!A1:Z200"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3 Where toDate(Col1) > date '"& TEXT( Today() , "yyyy-MM-dd" ) & "' And toDate(Col1 ) <= date '"& TEXT( EOMONTH( Today() , 1) , "yyyy-MM-dd" ) & "' "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=query(ImportRange("1YHvYS1-rc1n56CeVeBynZRP6YCtTTyHkVhdu-Wa8E4s=en#","Alt Single Signup!A1:Z200"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 Where toDate(Col1) > date '"& TEXT( Today() , "yyyy-MM-dd" ) & "' And toDate(Col1 ) <= date '"& TEXT( EOMONTH( Today() , 1) , "yyyy-MM-dd" ) & "' ")
```

Let me know if you have a problem.